# How to read a file and store it in array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, store

I want to read a text file and store it as string multidimensional array in java.

The input will be like this

11 12 13

12 11 16

33 45 6

I want to store this in

```
 String[][] as={{"11","12","13"},
       {"12","11","16"},
       {"33","45"}};
```

My code

```
String file="e:\\s.txt";

         try
       {
       int counterCol=0,counterRow=0;

       String[][] d=null;

       BufferedReader bw=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));


        String str=bw.readLine();

        String[] words=str.split(",");

        System.out.println(words.length+"Counterrow");

    counterCol=words.length; //get total words split by comma : column

         while(bw.readLine()!=null)
        {

            counterRow++;    
  // to get the total words as it gives total row count
        }

         String[][] d=new String[counterRow][counterCol];
        for(int x=0;x<counterRow;x++)
        {

            for(int y=0;y<counterCol;y++)
            {

       d[x][y]=bw.readLine();  
   //storing in array. But here gives me the exception
            }

        }
```

But I cannot store it in array as I getting null pointer exception. How to over come this problem

Comment: Initialize your array d

Comment: d[x][y] = new String[counterCol][counterRow];

Comment: yes i changed and initialized. But i couldn't store my values and retrieve back. Getting null

Comment: FYI:  Your data example doesn't have any commas.  If the data in the file is the same, then what you have won't work because you are splitting the line with `String[] words=str.split(",");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few things wrong here:

1. Array not initialized
2. You are not looping over the file lines using the `BufferedReader`
3. You are splitting by comma instead of space as specified in your sample data

Using Java [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) will help you here. Specifically [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Give something like this a go:

```
String file="e:\\s.txt";

        try {
            int counterRow = 0;

            String[][] d = new String[1][1];

            BufferedReader bw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            List<List<String>> stringListList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

            String currentLine;

            while ((currentLine = bw.readLine()) != null) {
                if (currentLine != null) {
                    String[] words = currentLine.split(" ");
                    stringListList.add(Arrays.asList(words));
                }
            }

            // Now convert stringListList into your array if needed
            d = Arrays.copyOf(d, stringListList.size());

            for (List<String> stringList : stringListList) {

                String[] newArray = new String[stringList.size()];

                for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
                    newArray[i] = stringList.get(i);
                }

                d[counterRow] = newArray;

                counterRow ++;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You get NullPointer because your array 'd' is null:

```
String[][] d=null;
```

Initialize it and it should be work:

```
String[][] d= new String [counterCol][counterRow];
```